# How do you programmatically determine whether a Windows computer is a member of a domain?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dns

I need a way to determine whether the computer running my program is joined to any domain. It doesn't matter what specific domain it is part of, just whether it is connected to anything. I'm coding in vc++ against the Win32 API.

Comment: Any domain, or specific domain? Probably you're gonna want WMI...

Comment: Related question to [check for a particular domain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4715512/588306) (and in [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1290826/588306)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Straight from Microsoft:

[How To Determine If a Windows NT/Windows 2000 Computer Is a Domain Member](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179891)

This approach uses the Windows API. From the article summary:

> This article describes how to
>   determine if a computer that is
>   running Windows NT 4.0 or Windows 2000
>   is a member of a domain, is a member
>   of a workgroup, or is a stand-alone
>   computer using the Local Security
>   Authority APIs.

The article also provides sample code for a small program that outputs whether the computer the program is running on is part of a domain, part of a workgroup, or a standalone computer.

Comment: Note that you do not nead the GENERIC_READ permission if you are going to just check if the machine is domain-joined (and also get the domain name). GENERIC_READ requires elevation, whereas using just POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION does not.

Comment: That link is broken now.

Comment: https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/179891

Answer (score 4):

I think the [NetServerEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370623%28VS.85%29.aspx) function will help you in what you want; I would ask for the primary domain controllers with the `SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_CTRL` constant for *servertype* parameter. If you don't get any, then you're not in a domain.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dead simple approach I don't see mentioned.

```
TCHAR UserDnsDomain[128] = { 0 }; 
DWORD Result = 0;

Result = GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN", UserDnsDomain, sizeof(UserDnsDomain));

if (Result == 0 || Result >= sizeof(UserDnsDomain) || GetLastError() == ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    return(FALSE); // Not logged in to a domain
}
```

This is predicated on the idea that if the user who is running this code is not currently logged in to a domain, then the USERDNSDOMAIN environment variable will be empty or unavailable. But there are some caveats you should think about.

Pros:

- Very easy to implement.
- 99% reliable.

Cons:

- May fail or return false results if the computer is domain joined, but the user executing this code is logged on to that computer with a local account.
- May fail or return false results if the computer is domain joined, but network connectivity to a domain controller was unavailable at the time of logon/user logged on with cached credentials.

Comment: May also fail if the user running the command is SYSTEM.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the MSDN sample is a little outdated. This is the function I came up with that works.

```
bool ComputerBelongsToDomain()
{
    bool ret = false;

    LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objectAttributes;
    LSA_HANDLE policyHandle;
    NTSTATUS status;
    PPOLICY_PRIMARY_DOMAIN_INFO info;

    // Object attributes are reserved, so initialize to zeros.
    ZeroMemory(&objectAttributes, sizeof(objectAttributes));

    status = LsaOpenPolicy(NULL, &objectAttributes, GENERIC_READ | POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, &policyHandle);
    if (!status)
    {
        status = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(policyHandle, PolicyPrimaryDomainInformation, (LPVOID*)&info);
        if (!status)
        {
            if (info->Sid)
                ret = true;

            LsaFreeMemory(info);
        }

        LsaClose(policyHandle);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon for the value of 'CachePrimaryDomain'.

Comment: MSDN says this key is no longer in use as of Windows 2000, but was kept for backwards compat. This makes me wonder if it is safe to use?

Comment: @kgriffs It's not available on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

what about from the name of the computer?

**edit:** this was a crapy 'answer' from way back. What I meant was cheching for the form `domain\name` in the computer name. That of course implies that you do know the name of the domain, it does not solves the issue of just knowing if the computer is in any domain.

Comment: As far as I know, all Windows computers have to have a name, regardless of whether they're on a network or not.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid LSA which is a wrong method.
You must use DS api (2 lines of code)

Comment: do you have a link to the MSDN page for that API?

Comment: I'm guessing he's referring to using [DSBind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675931(v=vs.85).aspx).  Note that it only works on Vista/2008 and newer.