# How can my program detect whether it's running on a particular domain?

Tags: delphi, winapi, active-directory, dns

I have the need to restrict specific functions of an application based on the location of the currently logged in user. As I have to implement this logic in Delphi, I'd prefer not to go overboard with full active directory/LDAP queries.

My curent thought is to utilize DsGetDcName, and use the GUID returned in the DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO structure and compare it to a hard coded constant. It seems to reason that a domain GUID would only change if the domain is recreated, so this would provide functionality that I desire with limited overhead. My only concern is that I can't find any documentation on MSDN confirming my assumption.

```
type
  EAccessDenied = Exception;
  EInvalidOwner = Exception;
  EInsufficientBuffer = Exception;
  ELibraryNotFound = Exception;

  NET_API_STATUS = Integer;

  TDomainControllerInfoA = record
    DomainControllerName: LPSTR;
    DomainControllerAddress: LPSTR;
    DomainControllerAddressType: ULONG;
    DomainGuid: TGUID;
    DomainName: LPSTR;
    DnsForestName: LPSTR;
    Flags: ULONG;
    DcSiteName: LPSTR;
    ClientSiteName: LPSTR;
  end;
  PDomainControllerInfoA = ^TDomainControllerInfoA;

const
  NERR_Success = 0;

procedure NetCheck(ErrCode: NET_API_STATUS);
begin
  if ErrCode <> NERR_Success then
  begin
    case ErrCode of
      ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
        raise EAccessDenied.Create('Access is Denied');
      ERROR_INVALID_OWNER:
        raise EInvalidOwner.Create('Cannot assign the owner of this object.');
      ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
        raise EInsufficientBuffer.Create('Buffer passed was too small');
      else
        raise Exception.Create('Error Code: ' + IntToStr(ErrCode) + #13 +
          SysErrorMessage(ErrCode));
    end;
  end;
end;

function IsInternalDomain: Boolean;
var
  NTNetDsGetDcName: function(ComputerName, DomainName: PChar; DomainGuid: PGUID; SiteName: PChar; Flags: ULONG; var DomainControllerInfo: PDomainControllerInfoA): NET_API_STATUS; stdcall;
  NTNetApiBufferFree: function (lpBuffer: Pointer): NET_API_STATUS; stdcall;
  LibHandle: THandle;
  DomainControllerInfo: PDomainControllerInfoA;
  ErrMode: Word;
const
  NTlib = 'NETAPI32.DLL';
  DS_IS_FLAT_NAME = $00010000;
  DS_RETURN_DNS_NAME = $40000000;
  INTERNAL_DOMAIN_GUID: TGUID = '{????????-????-????-????-????????????}';
begin
 if Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then
    begin
    ErrMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
    LibHandle := LoadLibrary(NTlib);
    SetErrorMode(ErrMode);
    if LibHandle = 0 then
        raise ELibraryNotFound.Create('Unable to map library: ' + NTlib);
    try
      @NTNetDsGetDcName := GetProcAddress(Libhandle, 'DsGetDcNameA');
      @NTNetApiBufferFree       := GetProcAddress(Libhandle,'NetApiBufferFree');
      try
        NetCheck(NTNetDsGetDcName(nil, nil, nil, nil, DS_IS_FLAT_NAME or DS_RETURN_DNS_NAME, DomainControllerInfo));
        Result := (DomainControllerInfo.DomainName = 'foo.com') and (CompareMem(@DomainControllerInfo.DomainGuid,@INTERNAL_DOMAIN_GUID, SizeOf(TGuid)));//WideCharToString(pDomain);
      finally
        NetCheck(NTNetApiBufferFree(DomainControllerInfo));
      end;
    finally
      FreeLibrary(LibHandle);
    end;
    end
 else
  Result := False;
end;
```

Added a related question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/223498/a-unique-identifier-for-a-domain) as suggested.

Found another interesting read on [Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx) which also seems to hint at me being right, but isn't specifically scoped at domain SID's.

Comment: I'd agree that the GUID wouldn't change but I'd like to point out that you would certainly receive a different GUID if the domain controller changes.

Comment: Noting I am using the domain GUID, not the DC guid. As such (one would think) it would require demoting/removing all DC's and workstations, and migrating them to a new domain.  I am under the assumption that the domain GUID is created when you promote the first server to a domain controller, and then it lives on for the life of the domain.

Comment: Ok, my bad, sorry. I'd agree with your assumption, unfortunately I haven't seen it stated anywhere. Maybe you'd want to ask this at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Create a service account on the domain;

Get the GUID of the service account and encrypt it and save it somewhere (registry) maybe as part of enterprise install process to validate a license agreement.

On startup of the client app query for the Domain Service Account GUID and validate it with the saved GUID.

Or create your own enterprise 'key' server.

Doing an LDAP query is easier than doing all the domain controller crap.

Answer (score 1):

If I correct understand your requirement the best API in your case is [GetUserNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724435%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can choose the value of `NameFormat` parameter of the type [EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724268%28VS.85%29.aspx) which you can better verify. Another function [GetComputerNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724301%28VS.85%29.aspx) is helpful if you want additionally verify the information about the computer where the program is running.

Comment: However, I am not attempting to validate the user directly here. While I could get a variety of responses back, the underlying paranoia I have is someone could still generate a dummy internal domain name with this same name and acheive incorrect results. If I can restrict based on the Domain SID, I would feel much safer (maybe incorrectly).

Answer (score 0):

> I have the need to restrict specific
>   functions of an application based on
>   the location of the currently logged
>   in user

If you are trying to find out the location of the currently logged in ***user***, you shouldn't be using *DsGetDcName*.

Your computer can be joined to **domainA**.  Your logon user can be from **domainB**.  Calling *DsGetDcName* on your computer doesn't give you **domainB GUID** but it will give you **domainA GUID**

Therefore, I think you should use [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  The *LookupAccountName* gives you the currently logged in user's SID.  Then, you can extract the domain SID from the user SID.  That domain SID is really the domain where this user coming from.  For the details of how to extract a domain SID from a user SID, please check [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962011.aspx)

Regarding to your original question about the uniqueness of the domain GUID, I am sorry that I don't have answer on it.  AFAIK, there is no tool available allowing you to change the domain SID nor the GUID.  I am not sure how hard to hack into it and change it.

Comment: I hadn't considered that route, however domain SID's are only garanteed to be unique across a single enterprise. I'm under the impression that a domain GUID should be uniqe world wide, as the probability of a CoCreateGUID call returning a duplicate GUID is very very slim.  Maybe I should use a combination of the 2 methods, the domain GUID check to ensure the proper domain (not a ghosted/dummy one), and then utilizing LookupAccountName to ensure the current user is a member of that domain?

Comment: @jchoover Yes, I think I understand what you are worrying.  You don't want somebody to setup a dummy domain with the same domain name and same domain SID.  As I said, I don't see any tool helping you to make sure what a domain SID going to look like.  If he can change the domain SID (e.g. by changing the NTDS.DIT file directly), he can probably use the same trick to change the domain GUID as well.  I think you are just over paranoid.  Hacker may also simply disassemble your code and patch your code to check against his own domain GUID.

Comment: @jchoover BTW, I agree that GUID is less likely to be identical by accident than SID.