# Restrict Delphi 7 pgm to corporate LAN

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, lan, restrict

Situation: i have a licencing program that i wrote in Delphi 7, this allows users to create licences for products that have been sold.  There is a security risk with this because any employee could sell the products from home and take the licencing program home and create licences - they would be stealing and we would never know!

I thought it might be a good idea to restrict the licencing pgm to run only when its inside the corporate lan.

Is it advisable to do things like looking for the existance of a named server, or to test if its being run on a particular subnet?  And if so any examples would be welcome :)

Comment: Previously asked (no accepted answers though): [How can my program detect whether it's running on a particular domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715512).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to include in the mix is the domain of the computer. Most businesses have a domain that will be harder to reproduce. For an app you are developing for internal use, you could check for presence of a number of servers too.

Comment: But just to check for some servers isn't very secure. Using VMWare or other virtualization software you can reproduce any network environment you want.

Comment: @Robert I didn't claim secure, just part of the mix. A casual person is not going to bother setting up a matching domain and servers. Add more to secure as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There is one easy solution: Make it a web service or at least implement the license creation only on a an application that runs on one or more servers. This would allow everybody who can access the server(s) via network to create licenses. Outside of your network - protected by a firewall - no access is possible and therefore no-one can create licenses on his/her own.

Comment: thanks.  maybe i'll investigate the web service idea because if someone has access to the server they could copy the licencing program onto a usb and take it wherever they like

Comment: the server room should be locked ... ;)

Comment: If you want to make your license generator app 100% "uncopyable" you need special hardware like a crypto token, smartcard or a trusted platform module.