# How to implement software registration for domain users?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, dns, visual-c++

My application is running in a domain. It's installed on each Windows PC in this domain. Customers can buy a domain license and register it once, on a server for example. Then domain users on other PCs don't have to register it again. In the case where there are lots of PCs in a domain, registering on each one is quite annoying.

Is it possible to implement the registration this way? The application is coded in C++ and running on Windows, what's the easiest way to implement it?

Comment: Do you specifially mean ["Windows Domain"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain)? As in Active Directory?

Comment: Correct, it's "Windows Domain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206172/how-do-you-programmatically-determine-whether-a-windows-computer-is-a-member-of) to determine the AD domain. You'd want to do something similar, I think: get the domain, and check if that domain object holds your license information.

(AD is implemented on top of LDAP nowadays, and the Microsoft schema can be extended)