# Getting primary domain SID without admin privileges

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dns, sid

I'm trying to obtain computer's primary domain SID on windows using C++. I have manged to do that using `LsaQueryInformationPolicy` with `PolicyPrimaryDomainInformation`parameter. I've opened LSA policy for this operation as given:

```
auto lsaStatus = LsaOpenPolicy(Server, &ObjectAttributes, GENERIC_READ | POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, &PolicyHandle);
```

Unfortunatelly, using `LSAOpenPolicy` requiers administrator privileges to run and for the project I'm working on, it cannot, since most of the users will not have it. My question is - is there any way of obtaining current computer's primary domain SID without invoking admin rights? If there is, how should I go about doing that using Visual C++/MFC?

Comment: Perhaps GetComputerObjectName followed by LookupAccountName and GetWindowsAccountDomainSid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution to this problem. Turns out I made wrong assumption based on incorrect API description on MSDN. 
As we can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378299(v=vs.85).aspx), `LsaOpenPolicy` seems to require administrator privileges and article about [Access Masks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892(v=vs.85).aspx) did not say nor did it lead me anywhere where I could find any information about needed privileges. However thanks to stack overflow user [TripShock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179895/tripshock) and his comment on similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206172/how-do-you-programmatically-determine-whether-a-windows-computer-is-a-member-of) I found out that actually using only `POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION` access flag will not invoke admin rights. Tested it in my program and a virtual machine and turns out to be true.